# D3.js : a graph where axis are the lines of a triangle (ternary plot)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to build a datanets where each axes (3) are the lines of a triangle.
But I can't find any clue / tutorial / part of the API that could help.

I tried to learn more on parallel-coordinates (http://eagereyes.org/techniques/parallel-coordinates) but it's not what I needed. I am now considering [ternary plots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_plot) like this:

[image: Example ternary plot showing flamability of different combinations of methand-nitrogen-oxygen]

And I can't find a way in D3.js to rotate an axis in order to make my desirated triangle.

(I am a very new at both dataviz development and D3.js : please excuse any heresy.)

Comment: You can rotate an axis by selecting the element it is contained in and applying a rotation.

Comment: You could also just draw the axes yourself, as in these examples of ternary plots in d3: [simple plot](http://bl.ocks.org/widged/5780720), [more dense](http://bl.ocks.org/tomgp/7674234).  I think using a d3 axis function in a rotated coordinate space is probably easier for drawing ticks and labels, but you'll want to look at those examples as you figure out the custom code to get the grid lines correct and to translate your a:b:c composition data values into (x,y) coordinates.

Comment: Thanks for those exemples and solutions!

Comment: Thomas: Glad we got you off to a good start.  When you get it figured out, would you mind coming back and putting together a simplified code example (as an answer to the question) showing what you did?  Especially if you do end up using a d3 axis function, but rotated, in combination with the ideas from those other examples, it could be a useful reference for others.

Comment: Amelia: As a matter of fact, I am doing something much more visual than data complex. I checked other visualization libraries and SnapSVG (heir of Raphael.js) matched my needs perfectly. 

SnapSVG being a drawing library I drawn my ternary plot "all by hand" (axis, ticks and points) ie. :